# What's the latest sphinx version which supports Python 2.7?

Tags: python-sphinx, python-2.x, deprecated, packaging, type-hinting

I am having trouble packaging Sphinx v4.2 on Python v2.7.18:

```
========== 1733 passed, 3 skipped, 3477 warnings in 663.79s (0:11:03) ==========
==> Entering fakeroot environment...
==> Starting package()...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    import sphinx
  File "/home/user/Projects/aur/python2-sphinx/src/Sphinx-4.2.0/sphinx/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .deprecation import RemovedInNextVersionWarning
  File "/home/user/Projects/aur/python2-sphinx/src/Sphinx-4.2.0/sphinx/deprecation.py", line 28
    def deprecated_alias(modname: str, objects: Dict[str, object],
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since the above error regards Python 3.x typehinting and installing `python2-typing` didn't make a difference, I am guessing python 2 support must have been deprecated, so

what's the latest sphinx version supporting Python 2.x?

Comment: Support for Python 2.7 was dropped in Sphinx 2.0.0: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html#id111.

Comment: I ended up packaging `1.8.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest [`PKGBUILD`](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-community/commit/6e5ab1cee3caf61615b7e7298ebe23111e638fe0) for `python2-sphinx` was for version `1.8.5`.